# Idiosyncratic risk (t statistic)

Tags: volatility, statistics

I am working on idiosyncratic volatility analysis and I would like to control for size characteristics following the method used in the paper "[The Cross-Section of Volatility and Expected Returns](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.1540-6261.2006.00836.x)" by Ang et al (2006).

In Table 7, they implement a double sorting method which is clear to me, but I do not understand how they calculate the t statistic of the "controlling for size" row. The "controlling for size" is the average of the five quintiles' alphas, but can anyone help on how to compute the t statistic of that value?

[image]

Comment: The t-stat is based on the mean alpha and the standard deviation of the alpha. Since you have 5 categories for your size adjustment, the big mean is the average of the 5 means as you said. For the big standard deviation, you take the square root of the *Pooled Variance* from the 5 categories https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pooled_variance . Since the 5 cats are of equal size it is just the mean of the 5 variances.

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much for your answer.